# Proof (?) about weak contractions. Please check to see if I'm going about this correctly?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $f:M \rightarrow M$ satisfies that $\forall x,y \in M$, if $x≠y$ then $d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y)$, then $f$ is a weak contraction.

Is a weak contraction a contraction?

I saw a counter example on stack exchange, but I didn't really believe it, and I have a proof that I think works.  Here it is:

If $f$ is a weak contraction, and $x≠y$, then:

$d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y)$ and $\frac{d(f(x),f(y))}{d(x,y)}<1$

Let $1>k = c\frac{d(f(x),f(y))}{d(x,y)} > \frac{d(f(x),f(y))}{d(x,y)}$ for some $c>0$.

Then, $d(f(x),f(y))<kd(x,y)$ $\forall x,y \in M$ where $x≠y$.

Am I missing something about my proof?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your inequality $c\frac{d(f(x),f(y))}{d(x,y)} > \frac{d(f(x),f(y))}{d(x,y)}$ is false when $c < 1$.

Comment: True, but it's true for some c.  I believe for $f$ to be a contraction, I just need to find some constant $k$ for which $d(f(x),f(y)) \leq kd(x,y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof does not make sense and you are trying to prove something that is false.

To see the problem, you need to be extremely clear about your quantifiers.  To show that $f$ is a contraction, you have to find a *single* number $k$ which works for *every* $x,y$.  You do not get to let $k$ depend on $x,y$!  As your proof stands, you choose $c$ depending on $x,y$, and therefore your $k$ depends on $x,y$.  That's bad.

A typical counterexample for this claim is to take the metric space $(0,1)$ and let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$.

To see $f$ is a weak contraction, note that for any $x,y$ we have

$$|f(x)- f(y)| = \frac{1}{2}|x^2 - y^2| = \frac{1}{2} (x+y)|x-y|.$$

Since $x,y \in (0,1)$, we have $x+y < 2$, hence $|f(x) - f(y)| < |x-y|$.

But $f$ is not a contraction.  For any $k < 1$, let $x,y$ be distinct real numbers in $(k,1)$.  Then 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| = \frac{1}{2} (x+y) |x-y| > \frac{1}{2} (k+k) |x-y| = k|x-y|.$$
So for that $k$ value, it is not true that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le k|x-y|$ for all $x,y$, since we have produced $x,y$ for which it fails.  The same argument works for any $k$, so there cannot be any $k$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le k|x-y|$ for all $x,y$.

It may be helpful to try more concrete examples.  Say you think it is a contraction with $k=0.9$.  Well, take $x=0.95$ and $y=0.96$.  You can check that $\frac{|f(0.95)-f(0.96)|}{|0.95 - 0.96|} = 0.955 > 0.9$ so that doesn't work.  If you think $k=0.99$ works, take $x=0.995$ and $y=0.996$.  No matter what $k < 1$ you think might work, you can find $x,y$ that show that it actually doesn't.

Comment: Okay!  Thanks so much!  I guess I was misunderstanding what it meant for $f$ to be a contraction.